# std::istringstream iss(std::move(string)); crosses the initialization though it's out side loop

Tags: c++, c++11

Initially I wrote `std::istringstream iss(std::move(string));` inside while loop so gave error `crosses initialization` inside loop. Now it's not inside any loop but even it gives error `crosses the initialization`.

```
void *SocketHandler(void *lp)
{
    typedef std::unordered_map<std::string,int> occurrences;
    occurrences s1;
    std::string ss;
    std::ostringstream bfr;
    std::string result_string;
    std::vector<std::string> most;
    int max_count = 0;
    int tmp=0;

    while ((NULL != word) && (50 > i)) {
        ch[i] = strdup(word);
        excluded_string[j]=strdup(word);
        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        skp = BoyerMoore_skip(ch[i], strlen(ch[i]) );
        bfr << excluded_string[j] << " ";
        result_string = bfr.str();
        j++;
        //  std::cout << "string is :" << r1;
        i++;
        if(str==NULL && str==NULL and skp !=NULL)
        {
            pcount=0;
            ncount=0;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "string is :" << result_string << "\n";
    std::istringstream iss(std::move(result_string));  // **Here it gives error**

    while (iss >> result_string)
    {
        tmp = ++s1[result_string];
        if (tmp == max_count)
        {
            most.push_back(result_string);
        }
        else if (tmp > max_count)
        {
            max_count = tmp;
            most.clear();
            most.push_back(result_string);
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "Maximum Occurrences" << std::endl;
    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = most.cbegin(); it != most.cend(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this in a case of a switch?

Comment: @chris: No not in switch

Comment: @Karimkhan, Oh, the wording of the error reminded me of that problem.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: It was error when int var initialization in while loop. This question has different issue!

Comment: @Karimkhan: Still: post a [complete example](http://sscce.org/) exhibiting the problem!

Comment: It can be solved if I can declare `std::istringstream iss` and then mmove string when required. I googled for how to move string to iss, but I could not find out correct sysntax!

Comment: I'm still trying to find `reslut_string` somewhere in this code, as well as deciphering whether " function declaration part " means in some special proximity of the function open brace, or the parameter list.

Comment: @Karimkhan: note that _all_ code is not a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)!

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I took care to remove unwanted code and gave only required

Comment: No, you didn't: the code spits out all kind of other errors!

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Try to understand, If you add other initialization  and other code then it would be too long and no one would prefer to read it!

Comment: @Karimkhan I helped you with the initial loop a day or two ago. As written this cannot compile. Look at the string passed to the `iss` constructor. The name is `reslut_string`. I'm quite sure you don't want that.

Comment: Better if someone target the real issue!

Comment: @Karimkhan: The code snippets you post **do not** show the problem you want to get solved! How do you expect to get an answer showing code which doesn't have the problem? I don't want to see all your code! I want to see, however, a [short, self-contained, exmaple](http://sscce.org) showing the problem!

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Yes it was typo while I posted the question. I checked my code and corrected but issue still persist!

Comment: @Karimkhan: OK, you have posted about 3-4 code snippets. And your text ***does not*** make it clear which one is exhibiting the problem. Please remove all code that is ***not directly*** showing the problem. Then take the remaining code and change it so that it's short enough for us to actually run a version of it.

Comment: @Karimkhan: "*If you add other initialization and other code then it would be too long and no one would prefer to read it!*" Then you need to change your code so that it's shorter, without the initialization, ***but still compiles and shows your problem***.

Answer (score 0):

Cross initialization appearing here: `std::istringstream iss(std::move(string));`

```
std::istringstream iss; 
iss.str(result_string);
```

which is equivalent to `std::istringstream iss(std::move(result_string));` solved the issue

As @Dietmar explained:

Here there is no str() overload taking a std::string&& but only one taking a std::string const&. After all, the stream won't use the std::string anyway and just copy the characters into its internal buffer (with std::string now being guaranteed to represent their value using contiguous memory it would be possible for std:stringbuf to internally use a std::string mostly but the stream buffers want to provide unused space, at least, for output but the buffer is shared between input and output).